# Node module using requirejs and typescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, requirejs, typescript

I use requirejs and typescript for a node_module.

https://github.com/Ayolan/validator-extended/blob/master/app.js

It works but I cannot load it once installed from npm.
It looks like the requirejs config on the node_module change the config of my project (baseUrl and nodeRequire config actually).

There is a way to use TS and requirejs on a node_module?

Comment: Why are you using RequireJS in a Node.js module? Node.js has its own module loading

Comment: To load typescript files. (AMD)

Comment: You can compile TypeScript files to the CommonJS spec (used by node). Pass in the `--module "commonjs"` to the compiler

Comment: But... I know that. But you can't require them with the basic node.js require() function, you need something like requirejs.

Comment: You should be able to. Nodejs' `require` has got nothing to do with `RequireJS`. It's a different module system. Therefore if you compile your TypeScript to commonjs modules it should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: No, it shouldn't, you can't require a AMD file server side without define a define() function that takes the file names to require before require the function. If you try it, you will get "define() is not defined". BTW you cannot do it client side neither without requirejs or equivalent.

Comment: It's **not** an AMD file, that's the whole point I'm making... By compiling TypeScript to CommonJS modules instead of AMD you can use them in your nodejs application. You do not need RequireJS.

Comment: You're right. I forgot that, but i did like this because I'm extending another node.js module and this module is AMD compatible, so I wanted to do it AMD compatible too. But it's kinda difficult because if I write it using AMD compilation, you NEED to ue requirejs to require it, if I don't, it's not respecting the AMD compatible base library. And I can't use some code to make it both compatible from a require and AMD in the typescript source code I guess, or I don't know how do it. For the moment I removed the .ts file and requirejs use, so I use directly the .js file and I think that's easier

Comment: Add this information to your question so it's clear what you're looking for in an answer. From the top of my head, I can't provide you with an answer to your updated question

Comment: I won't, I guess that the answer is to don't use requirejs, you were right about use require but I need to compile in commonJs instead of AMD. I misunderstood two things, MAD compatible doesn't means that I need to use requirejs. Use commonJs instead of AMD should solve this issue. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I'm glad I could help, I'll consolidate this as an answer. Could you please accept so that this question is closed?

Comment: Please edit this question so it aligns with the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js does not use the AMD specification for JavaScript modules but instead the CommonJS modules. You'll need to tell the TypeScript compiler to compile your modules to this specification. This can be easily achieved by passing in the `--module "commonjs"`flag to the compiler.

Please note, that although the CommonJS spec uses the `require` keyword, this is something completely different than `RequireJS`. Node.js does not rely on RequireJS for it's module loading, it has its own module loader that is based on the CommonJS spec.

In short: try to avoid using RequireJS and node.js.

Answer (score 2):

His question makes sense. Using requirejs in node has a number of advantages over the standard commonjs: http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html

How to build node modules with AMD / Requirejs:
http://requirejs.org/docs/node.html#nodeModules

Comment: I agree. I prefer starting my files with define and using dependency injection for Node over the traditional, CommonJS approach. It personally has the advantage of keeping my code clean and files small and simple.

Answer (score 2):

**If you don't need requirejs AND node at the same time**
*That was my case when I had 2 separated typescript builds, one for the front and one for the back but I had only one package.json to put all the "@types" in so tsc would pick both .d.ts in `node_modules/@types`*

You can just manually tell tscto take certain types with the type option:

`types: [ "requirejs" ]` for the front and `types: [ "node" ]` for the back

Hope this helps.

Comment: That feature didn't exist back then, thanks for the tip! :)